# How to make a column sortable in bootstrap 4 table

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I want to make a column in bootstrap table sortable, I followed the documents here https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#column-options/sortable.html
and even do I added `data-sortable="true"` to column and to table I don't havr the sort functionaluty.
I only got the arrows of the sort functionality but they don't work

when I use the example https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcomes/from-data.html - the sortable functionality works fine, only when I change the example to use data from data (according to this: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcomes/from-data.html#view-source) the sort stop working.

Table definition

```
<div id="toolbar">
  <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete
  </button>
</div>
<table
  id="table"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-search="true"
  data-show-refresh="true"
  data-show-toggle="true"
  data-show-fullscreen="true"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
  data-detail-view="true"
  data-show-export="true"
  data-click-to-select="true"
  data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
  data-minimum-count-columns="2"
  data-show-pagination-switch="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-id-field="Name"
  data-page-list="[1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-response-handler="responseHandler">


  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true" >Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>




</table>
```

Scripts

```
$(function() {
    var data = [
      {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 'Item 0',
        'price': '$0'
      },
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Item 1',
        'price': '$1'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Item 2',
        'price': '$2'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Item 3',
        'price': '$3'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'Item 4',
        'price': '$4'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'name': 'Item 5',
        'price': '$5'
      }
    ]
    $table.bootstrapTable({data: data})
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the script tag and initialized var $table = $('#table') now it is working

```
    <script>
  var $table = $('#table')

  $(function() {
    var data = [
      {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 'Item 0',
        'price': '$0'
      },
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Item 1',
        'price': '$1'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Item 2',
        'price': '$2'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Item 3',
        'price': '$3'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'Item 4',
        'price': '$4'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'name': 'Item 5',
        'price': '$5'
      }
    ]
    $table.bootstrapTable({data: data})
  })
</script>
```

Comment: It's still not working, it's not actually sort anything I just have the sorting arrows on the top of the column...